# partition of the set of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $S=\{s_i\}_{i\geq 0}$ any infinite set of positive integers for
>   which $c=\max \{|s_{i+1}-s_i|:i \geq 0\}$ exists.
>
> Let $T_0=S$ and define the sets $T_1, T_2,\dots, T_{c-1}$ recursively
>   by $$T_j=\{s+j: s\in S\}-\bigcup \limits_{i=0}^{j-1}T_i,$$ i.e., just
>   translate $S$ by $j$, and make sure that $T_j$ is disjoint from
>   previous $T_i$'s. Since $|s_{i+1}-s_i|\leq c$ for all $i\geq 0$, the
>   sets $T_0, T_1, T_2,\dots, T_{c-1}$ provide a partition of
>   $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

I am not able to grasp some moments  of above excerpt. So let me ask some questions:

1) Why the author considers only $T_0, T_1, T_2,\dots, T_{c-1}$? What if we add also $T_c, T_{c+1}, T_{c+2}$?

2) Also I cannot able to show that $T_0\sqcup T_1\sqcup T_2\sqcup \dots \sqcup T_{c-1}=\mathbb{Z}^+$. I have problems with showing that $\mathbb{Z}^+ \subset T_0\sqcup T_1\sqcup T_2\sqcup \dots \sqcup T_{c-1}$.

Suppose $m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ then $s_k\leq m <s_{k+1}$. If $m=s_k$ then $m\in T_0$ so assume that $s_k< m <s_{k+1}$ then $0<m-s_k<s_{k+1}-s_k \leq c$ so $m-s_k=t$ where $1\leq t \leq c-1$. Thus, $m\in T_0+t$. But how to show that $m\notin T_0\cup \dots T_{t-1}$?

Can anyone explain my questions, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your claim is false because $T_0 \cup \ldots \cup T_{c-1}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z} \cap [\min S, \infty)$, in particular if $\min S = 5$, then $\mathbb{Z}^+ \ni 4 \notin (T_0\cup \ldots \cup T_{c-1})$.

We can fix this easily assuming that $\min \mathbb{Z}^+ \in S$.

To answer your first question, we do not consider $T_c$ and other such sets, because they are empty which is because $T_0 \cup \ldots \cup T_{c-1}$ already cover whole $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Your second question can be solved in two ways:

1. Observe that if $m \in T_l$ for $l < t$, then you are also done, because even if $m \notin T_t$, then it is in $T_l$, that is, it does belong to one of these sets, and so belongs to their union.
2. Instead of picking any $s_k \in S$ pick $s_k = \max (S \cap [\min \mathbb{Z}^+,m])$, this way it is the biggest number smaller than $m$, and having $m \in T_l$ for $l < t$ would contradict your choice of $s_k$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply! It really helped me :) Let me ask you one stupid question? How to prove that $T_0 \cup T_1 \cup \dots \cup T_{c-1}\subset [\min S, \infty)$? What if one of these sets $T_i$ is empty? If $z\in T_0 \cup T_1 \cup \dots \cup T_{c-1}$ then if $z\in T_0$ then OK. What if $z\in T_j$ where $j\neq 0$ and $T_j= \varnothing$? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @RFZ Sure, but first I need you to explain how it is possible for both $z \in T_j$ and $T_j = \varnothing$ to be true at the same time?

Comment: That is why I said my question is quite stupid. What if one of $T_i$'s is empty? And we are going to prove that $T_0\cup T_1\cup \dots \cup T_{c-1}\subset [\min{S},\infty)$

Comment: Could you explain my last post, please? What if one of the $T_i$'s is empty?

Comment: @RFZ I am not sure if I understand your concern. Nothing happens if any of the $T_i$'s empty, you carry on normally, for example $\mathbb{R} \cup \varnothing \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @RFZ As for $T_0 \cup T_1 \cup \dots \cup T_{c-1}\subseteq [\min S, \infty)$, you can prove $T_j \subseteq [\min S, \infty)$ by observing that $\min T_j \geq \min S$.